# Calling the UserForm_Click subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, userform, method-call

I have a VBA userform and I would like it to close if the user clicks the mouse anywhere (preferably anywhere on screen, but I'll take anywhere within the userform as a workable 2nd best option).

Here's my single line of code within the `Userform_Click` subroutine, which is located in the userform code (not in a standard module, nor in 'this workbook', nor in a worksheet):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

The problem I have seems to be calling the `UserForm_Click` subroutine.  No matter where or how many times I click, it just never seems to be called.  This seems like it should be so simple, but I must be missing something somewhere.

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere, but I couldn't find an answer to this specific question in my searches.

Comment: Is the form blank?

Comment: If there are controls on the form, and you click on the control, then you arent actually clicking on the background of the form, so that event will not get triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BraX has solved it!

My userform is covered with a background image, so what I actually need to use is:

```
Private Sub Background_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Similiarly, for any other objects on the userform.

Thanks Brax!

Answer (score 0):

If there are controls on the form, and you click on the control, then you aren't actually clicking on the background of the form, so that event will not get triggered.